# Fill out form on websites from within code

Tags: javascript, forms, post

I'm working with websites that have forms on their pages. I need to fill out the form and then submit it, using Javascript.

The problem that I'm running into is that if I make a GET request in order to get the HTML of the page, then I don't have access to the JS running on that page and therefore, I can't actually submit the form (since the page is not connected to the server). How would I be able get around this? It could also be that some pages aren't running JS, but are running PHP scripts instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a headless browser in this case. Here's [one](http://xbrowser.codeplex.com/) for .NET, if you can code C#, otherwise there are plenty of others for different platforms and languages.